# Center vertically and center in the left half horizontally

Tags: css

How can I center the container 'position' vertically? Horizontally it should be centered in the left half of the screen (don't know how to explain that better).

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/gbgopon2/1/

```
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="position"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#background {
    background-color: #ddd;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    top: -3em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 1;
}

#position {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This addition should align div vertically and center in the left half:

```
#position {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 25%;
    right: 75%;
    margin: auto -50px; /* width / 2 */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gbgopon2/5/

Comment: Also, offset with `left: 25%;` - change 25%, if required, to your desired placement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using jQuery as well. The below code will automatically center the `div`(as you described) when the page loads and on window resize.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbgopon2/9/)

```
function position() {
  var width = $('#position').css('width').slice(0, -2) / 2;
  var height = $('#position').css('height').slice(0, -2) / 2;
  var fWidth = ($(window).width()) / 4;
  var fHeight = $(document).height() / 2;
  var top = fHeight - height;
  var left = fWidth - width;

  $('#position').css({
    'top': top + 'px',
    'left': left + 'px'
  });
}

position();

$(window).resize(function() {
  position();
});
```